# react-day-picker doesn't close if keepfocus is set to false

Tags: javascript, react-day-picker

I was trying to make a simple implementation of react-day-picker. But I found a problem when trying to close `DayPicker` container when it is triggered from `DayPickerInput` and the property `keepFocus` is set to `false`.

```
<DayPickerInput
    keepFocus={false}
    placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"
    format="DD/MM/YYYY"
/>
```

Here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/0mn32ryl0n

If you click inside the input the daypicker overlay is displayed correctly and if you click in a empty area of the overlay, then the overlay gets focused and it will be focused until you select one day, otherwise it won't be closed. So if you click in an area outside the overlay it can't be closed automatically.

The question would be, if this is the intended behavior or maybe I'm missing something. How can I close the DayPicker if a day is not selected and the overlay is already focused?

Comment: > _If you click inside the input the daypicker overlay is displayed correctly and if you click in a empty area of the overlay, then the overlay gets focused and it will be focused until you select one day_

This is not the behavior I get it, since I open the datepicker and I click outside, the panel disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up doing something like this,

```
let dayPickerInputRef = null;
function Example() {
  return (
    <div name="main-container">
      <h3>DayPickerInput</h3>
      <DayPickerInput
        ref={ref => (dayPickerInputRef = ref)}
        keepFocus={false}
        placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"
        format="DD/MM/YYYY" 
        dayPickerProps = {{
          onBlur: () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              const elClicked = document.activeElement,
                container = document.getElementsByName(`main-container`);
              if (container && !container[0].contains(elClicked)) {
                dayPickerInputRef.hideDayPicker();
              }
            }, 1);
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: doesnt work for me